# is there any software to establish N percent of internet speed to the processes?

Tags: internet, software-rec, bandwidth

I'm interesting to find a software to control my internet speed usage that would limite each process to use percent of internet speed.
or even any (speed or volume) limitation that would set to each process .

For example I want to establish 50% of internet speed to IDM , 30% utorrent and 20% to Windows update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) does this, although it has suffered a fair bit of bloating in the last decade.